# How do I handle the browser's "share page" intent in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I read here ( http://androidlittle.blogspot.com/2009/08/intent-filter-for-share-link.html ) what intent-filter is required to handle the "share link" intent that the android web browser sends. I have placed this inside an  block in my AndroidManifest.xml like so:

```
    <activity android:name=".ShareLink">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data/>
    </activity>
```

I cannot for the life of me get this to be triggered though. When I share a link in the android browser, the emulator log shows it's creating a chooser intent, but doesn't give the details of the intent the chooser is acting on. No chooser window pops up, and the intent gets handled by the SMS application.

I have also tried kicking off the intent manually:

```
adb shell am start -D -a android.intent.action.SEND -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT -t text/plain -d http://google.com/
```

but the response I get is:

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] dat=http://google.com/ typ=text/plain }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] dat=http://google.com/ typ=text/plain flg=0x10000000 }
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? My main (launcher) activity works fine, so I assume there is no issue with installation on the emulator.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

whoops!

Turns out, I had got the package installed initially but upon reinstallation it was silently failing. In between those two builds I fixed the manifest to be as you see above - the installed version didn't have the intent-filters specified, which obviously wouldn't work.

Guess I'll leave this here in case someone has the same need? Or should I just delete it?

Comment: I say leave it, because I just found what I was looking for thanks to your post.

Comment: well, your question got 9 upvotes, your answer got 7 upvotes, and the comments above got 6 upvotes.  I think the people have spoken ;)