# Getting the URL from browser

Tags: android, browser

How to get the URL from the Android browser?

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution : [How do I handle the browser's "share page" intent in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886556/how-do-i-handle-the-browsers-share-page-intent-in-android).

Comment: i can't undersatand this solution

Comment: You can not directly get the URL from the browser , the user needs to share feature to pass the data to your application

Comment: I need that my application remains pending until the user enters the url. He clicks on the browser and  at this moment I want to get the URL of the browser

Comment: I am sorry I have no idea how to do this, why dont you just provide the user with an input field , and get the url from there, if the url needs to be opened you can just call it after taking note of the URL