# How do I receive a "Share URL" from browser?

Tags: android, android-intent

I read this ( [How do I handle the browser's "share page" intent in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886556/how-do-i-handle-the-browsers-share-page-intent-in-android) ) which I can get the Share link to detect my app, now how do I get Activity to receive the URL?

Found Answer:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (savedInstanceState == null && intent != null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "intent != null");

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)");
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        messageText.setText(message);
        receiverText.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When your application receives the "Share page" from the browser, you could also get the title of the webpage:

```
String subject = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT);
```

Answer (score 5):

Once you have created an intent filter, your activity should pop up in the list of activities listening to the share link. Then use this in your activity:

```
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I put in my OnCreate for my Main Activity:

'Uri myI = getIntent().getData();
String myItext = myI.toString();
mEditText.setText(myItext);'

But it force closes once I try to convert it to string (line #2)

Comment: @James Oh my bad, when I answered this I had no access to an emulator/device to test it. I was going to suggest using extra string, but you've found the answer. Good work