# Get current URL using adb or python or perl

Tags: android

I want to get the current url the browser has in the address bar using any of the possible ways:

1. adb
2. python
3. perl

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the URL of current browser on the Phone ?

1. Can't
2. Nope
3. Yeah no.

But this [might be of vague interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886556/how-do-i-handle-the-browsers-share-page-intent-in-android) to you

---

Also how to get the browser history

I am abele to get history from following code

```
Cursor mCur = activity.managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                    Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
            mCur.moveToFirst();
            if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false) {
                    Log.v("titleIdx", mCur
                            .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX));
                    Log.v("urlIdx", mCur
                            .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX));
                    mCur.moveToNext();
                }
            }
```

You can run a service, you'll need the permission :`<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />`

In short, use

```
 adb shell am startservice <INTENT>
```

which starts your service that reads the URL

You're welcome.