# How to send highlighted text from default browser to Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, copy, copy-paste

I am new in Android Application Development.

**Research**: Before asking this question, I have read topics related with my question ([How to send string from one activity to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18146745/2752399)). Unfortunately they are explaining how to copy string from one activity to another activity.

**My intention**: User opens default browser of mobile phone, highlights text and clicks the button which will be added by me on menu and needed activity is opened with highlighted (copied) text

**Tried**: I have added intent filter to activity, then added action (android.intent.action.SEARCH) and category (android.intent.category.DEFAULT) into intent-filter. I thought, link for activity will be in Search section after Google, Google Translate, Wikipedia, Dictionary. Also, tried android.intent.action.ACTION_SEARCH_LONG_PRESS. Also, android.intent.action.SEND. Why it is not working, I have no idea.

**Tried(2)**: Found answer for my question partially from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2886556/2752399). But link for activity will be in Share->Share as Text->Activity. I think it is too long way.

```
<activity android:name="ActivityDate">
    <intent-filter android:label="Lesson">
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Questions** (I have many questions. I will try make them short and ask the ones that are most important for me)

> Question 1: Is it possible to add a button within menu (which opens when
>   text is highlighted. It includes copy, search, share)?
>
> Question 2: If it is possible, how to do that? How to make the button so
>   that when it is clicked, highlighted text should be send to my
>   activity?
>
> Question 3: If I could do this function for the default browser, can I implement to
>   other applications (3rd party applications)?